# How can I get my table to be fixed at the center?

Tags: html, reactjs, sass

I am still trying to get the hang on designing such stuff so please go easy on me. I am trying to design a table but the problem is that every time a new entry (a new row) is added, the table as a whole climbs up the page and the upper parts of it are no longer visible. I will leave my codes down below. Please let me know what I can do to make the table fixed at the middle and then to see the rest of the table, I can scroll down the website or maybe scroll down the table itself to see the rest of the content instead of the whole table just flying up

```
 <div className="container">
            <div className="myTable">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Decision</th>
                        <th>Federation Approval</th>
                        <th>Offer From</th>
                        <th>Transfer Type</th>
                        <th>Offer For</th>
                        <th>Player Current Club</th>
                        <th>Fee Offered in Millions</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
    
                    </tr>
                    {data.map((offer, key) => {
                        return (
                            <tr key={key}>
                                <td>{offer.decision}</td>
                                <td>{offer.fedApproval}</td>
                                <td>{offer.buyingClub}</td>
                                <td>{offer.transferType}</td>
                                <td>{offer.player}</td>
                                <td>{offer.sellingClub}</td>
                                <td>{offer.fee}</td>

                                <button className="approve" disabled={offer.fedApproval != "AWAITING       APPROVAL"} onClick={(e) => { handleApprove(e, offer.fedApproval, offer.buyingClub, offer.player) }}> Approve Offer</button>
                                <button className="disapprove" disabled={offer.fedApproval != "AWAITING APPROVAL"} onClick={(e) => { handleDisapprove(e, offer.fedApproval, offer.buyingClub, offer.player) }}> Disapprove Offer </button>
                                <Link to="/clubffpstatus" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
                                 <button className="checkStatus"> Check Club FFP Status</button>
                                </Link>
                            

                            </tr>
                        )
                    })}
                </table>
            </div>
            </div>
```

scss file:

```
.container {
        align-items: center;
        justify-items: center;
    .myTable {
        width: 100%;
        height: 50vh;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        justify-items: center;
        //overflow-y: scroll;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 0 auto;
  
        button {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: row;
          margin: 5px;
          cursor: pointer;
        }
  
        .approve {
          color: green;
          background-color: white;
          border-color: green;
          border-radius: 8px;
        }
  
        .approve:hover{
          transform:scale(1.1);
        }
  
        .approve:disabled{
          color: lightgray;
          border-color: lightgray;
          transform: none;
          cursor: default;
        }
  
        .disapprove {
          color: red;
          background-color: white;
          border-color: red;
          border-radius: 8px;
        }
  
        .disapprove:hover{
          transform:scale(1.1);
        }
  
        .disapprove:disabled{
          color: lightgray;
          border-color: lightgray;
          transform: none;
          cursor: default;
        }
  
        table {
          border: 2px solid blue;
          width: 800px;
          height: 200px;
          align-items: center;
          justify-items: center;
        }
      
        th {
          border-bottom: 1px solid black;
          gap: 0px;
        }
      
        td {
          text-align: center;
          border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        }
      }
    
  
    }
```

I tried to make a table in which I can see all the information and expected to be able to scroll down the website to see other entries when they are not visible but that did not happen the table would go up the page and eventually the upper entries no longer appear on the screen and I cannot scroll anywhere to see them

Comment: it seems the most critical css is commented `//overflow-y: scroll;`

but also "every time a new entry (a new row) is added" suggests the user is using a single page app opposed to a req/resp html page. so what does that mean?

Comment: @ABoston on another page on the webapp users can fill up a form and this form is stored in a firebase database, the table am designing is supposed to show the content of the database. So, every time a user fills the form and submits it, a new row is added to my table but this newly added row is making my whole table stretch upwards things like the column header name no longer appear on the page and are unreachable even with the overflow-y: scroll property

Comment: one user submits a form; another user (say admin or similar) makes a request to view recent data. so any "newly added" data is seen on a browser refresh not in the same session. its not angular ember or backbone. basically you want something like the above scrollable section for your code?!

Comment: Also a better solution for this. Look at `pagination`. otherwise data will grow and grow beyond a reasonable size for any admin or whoever has that job. your SQL will use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` (or similar). and here is a firebase paging link: https://fireship.io/lessons/firestore-pagination-guide/

Comment: @ABoston Yes! I wanted something scrollable like the code section. Sorry for the late reply